# The parameter 'inArray' is coming null. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, loadimage

I'm trying to load an image from a database.

I used this code in my view :

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Base64String)
{
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.ImageData);
    var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);

    <p>id:@item.NewsId</p>
    <img alt="" src="@imgSrc" style="height:100px;width:100px;" />
}
```

but I get this error in the browser:

> Value cannot be null.Parameter name: inArray

My model class:

```
public class News
{
    [Key]
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string MainComment { get; set; }
}
```

My controller :

```
WebContext db = new WebContext();

public ActionResult News()
{
       ViewBag.Base64String = db.AllNews.ToList();
       return View();
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.8), **`inArray is null`** refers to **`ArgumentNullException`**.

It means, in some of your records, **the field `ImageData` is empty or null**, which throws exception by ToBase64String.

you may use `if-clause` and set a default image, in case a record has no ImageData; for instance:

```
@if(item.ImageData != null) {  
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.ImageData);  
        var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64); 
        <img src = '@imgsrc'  
        style = "max-width:100px;max-height:100px" / >  
    }  
    else { 
          <img src = "~/img/avatar-default.jpg"  
                   style = "max-width:100px;max-height:100px" / > 
    }
```